# Navigation arrows in fancybox for pdf content

Tags: jquery, pdf, fancybox

I have fancybox set up so that it displays my pdf, however I would like it so that the fancybox left and right navigation arrows skip through the pdf slides...is that possible?

Thanks in advance.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(".pdf").click(function() {
            $.fancybox({
                'width': '100%',
                'height': '110%',
                'autoScale' : true,
                'autoDimensions': false,
                'cyclic' : true,
                'showNavArrows' : true,
                'titleShow' : true,
                'scrolling' : 'yes',
                'content': '<iframe src="'+this.href+'" type="application/pdf" height="99%" width="100%"></iframe>',
                'onClosed': function() {
                    $("#fancybox-inner").empty();
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can invoke the browsers PDF plugin by Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Just don't add a `rel` attribute to those elements with class `pdf`